# Adding custom scrollbars to part of a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to create a special place where I show a picture. It should have scroll bars (both horizontal and vertical) that look like this:

[image: thin gray scrollbar with small blue oval slider]

How can I get this look? Can I do it with an `iframe`? With a `div`?

Comment: Would'nt we all like a special place of our own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [jQuery scrollbar plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/scrollbar/) would probably be quickest and easiest

The [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) one is very easy to use and easy to skin

Comment: Thanks, but no one has the same look :(. I should slice a psd file with exactly the same look.

Comment: But the look is just styling, that's what I mean about the jQuery UI one being easy to skin - you can make it look how you want using CSS

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I better add the CSS3 option, although this won't work is some browsers so jQuery is probs your best bet.

Some info on CSS3 scrollbars:

http://css-tricks.com/9130-custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can do with HTML or CSS. If you're willing to use jQuery, Flash, &c., then you have numerous options, but that seems out of scope based on your tags.

Some versions of IE (5.5 - 8, not sure about 9) allow pages to set custom colors for scrollbar components using CSS, like this:

```
body {
    scrollbar-base-color: #000000;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-DarkShadow-Color: #888888;
}
```

However, that is non-standard and doesn't allow for the degree of customization you want.

Comment: I add jquery and javascript tags as well :))